# SQL Server equivalent of Oracle NVARCHAR2(X)

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle

Is the SQL Server datatype `NVARCHAR(510)` the equivalent of the Oracle datatype `NVARCHAR2(255)` (doubling because nvarchar2 in oracle) ?

Comment: I'd say it's roughly twice as big... :-?

Comment: I actually ask because there is the "2" in the Oracle NVARCHAR2 syntax, so I'm wondering if I should double the size when I use NVARCHAR in SQL Server to get something equivalent

Comment: That's just the name of the type. Size is provided within parenthesis.

Comment: For instance, SQL Server's `DATETIME2` can store one date, not two.

Comment: @scsimon in MS SQL it's not bytes. It's maximum number of charactes. 1 character = 2 bytes

Comment: Correct, hence the no need to double. Sorry, should have elaborated.

Comment: BTW, the Oracle type does not include the `CHAR` or `BYTE` modifier so it can actually mean both—it depends on server settings when you create the table.

Comment: Oracle uses a VARCHAR2 datatype to distinguish it from ANSI SQL  VARCHAR which differentiates between null and empty string and which Oracle does not (at least for the moment). In all other respects VARCHAR2 = VARCHAR.